# VS2019CE/VisualMicro project won't compile without specific reference

Tags: teensy

I have a small project to test a Sparkfun MPU9250 breakout board.  'Class_MPU9250BasicAHRS_t3.h', 'MPU9250BasicAHRS_t3.h' and 'Class_MPU9250BasicAHRS_t3.cpp' are all in the local project folder. Compile fails with an 'undefined reference' error at any reference to the Class_MPU9250BasicAHRS myIMU object  unless I add 'Class_MPU9250BasicAHRS_t3.cpp' to the project as a 'Source File' in the Solution Explorer window.

Why is this?  I thought the compiler was smart enough to look for a .cpp file with the same name as an #include'd header file.

TIA,

Code attached:

```
/*
    Name:       Teensy_MPU9250_Test.ino
    Created:    9/15/2019 11:46:10 AM
    Author:     FRANKWIN10\Frank
*/

/*  All this program does is display heading values from a Sparkfun MPU9250
    breakout board at the default (0x68) I2C address
*/

#include "Class_MPU9250BasicAHRS_t3.h" //extracted all #defines from MPU9250BasicAHRS_t3.ino
#include <i2c_t3.h>
#include <elapsedMillis.h>

elapsedMillis sinceLastPrint;
Class_MPU9250BasicAHRS myIMU;

int pulsePin = LED_BUILTIN;//04/10/18 added per-step pulse pin parameter
bool bFirstTime = true;
const long MSEC_PER_PRINT = 100;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(3000); //delay required to wait for Serial object creation
    //Wire.begin();

    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
    Wire.begin(I2C_MASTER, 0x00, I2C_PINS_18_19, I2C_PULLUP_EXT, 400000);
    Wire.setDefaultTimeout(200000); // 200ms

    //IMU init & test
    Serial.println("Starting program...");
    Serial.println("Initializing 9250 IMU...");
    myIMU.init9250IMU();
    Serial.println("Done...");
}

void loop()
{
    float hdg_deg = myIMU.GetIMUHeadingDeg();
    if (bFirstTime)
    {
        bFirstTime = false;
        Serial.printf("Msec\tHdg\n");
    }

    if (sinceLastPrint > MSEC_PER_PRINT)
    {
        Serial.printf("%lu\t%4.2f\n", millis(), hdg_deg);
        sinceLastPrint -= MSEC_PER_PRINT;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is probably by design, so that you could have files in the same folder that would not be processed by the compiler .... useful if you are testing different versions of the same file

Comment: Hmm, hadn't thought of that angle....